# HeaderText vs Design Name of Column in DataGrid

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I have the following code which works fine, but it gets the design name (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn11) of my column instead of the header text. How can I alter my code to get the header text on my column instead of the design name?

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdTransaction.Rows
            If grdTransaction.Item("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn11", row.Index).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                If grdTransaction("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn11", row.Index).Value.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

My convention for this kind of thing is to name the item as the database column name prefixed by dgc (DataGridColumn).  Thus the heading is 'Customer Name' and the columnname is 'dgcCustomerName'.  If you have more than one datagrid on the form or user control, and you have (for instance) CustomerId in columns in both grids, naming them the same creates a conflict.  dgcCustomerId is an object in the container namespace, allowing you to get property settings from it without having to specify the grid membership first.  That being the case, in the second grid you might have to call the column 'dgcInvoiceCustomerId' or 'dgcLineItemCustomerId'.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to return the column index from the DGV from supplied column header text:

```
Private Function getColID(ByVal colHeaderText As String) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer = -1
    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In grdTransaction.Columns
        If col.HeaderText = colHeaderText Then
            result = col.Index
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    return result
End Function
```

then in your code:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdTransaction.Rows
            If grdTransaction.Item(getColID("header text"), row.Index).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                If grdTransaction(getColID("header text"), row.Index).Value.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

or this little change:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdTransaction.Rows
            If row.cells(getColID("header text")).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                If row.cells(getColID("header text")).Value.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simple ..

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdTransaction.Rows

    If Not IsDBNull(row.cells("column_name").Value) Then

        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red

    End If

 Next
```

Comment: No, I'm getting the same error, that the column is not found. I need to put this: DataGridViewTextBoxColumn11 to make it work on your snippet. What I want, is to be able to enter the column Header Text as it appears when the form loads during run time. Thanks

Comment: @nectarines .. Dont put **DataGridViewTextBoxColumn11** to replace **column_name** .. replace it with your field name in your DB, because that is usually the header text if you didn't change it ..

Comment: @nectarines .. have you figured this out ?